# Saving Control Values to Class Object Property

Tags: vba, excel

I have this userform that I has a bunch of controls on it, and the control name corresponds to a property name that i have defined inside `OrderPrompts`.

When the user clicks on the save button, I am trying to save all those control values back to the original object `OrderPrompts`.

Here's the order prompts classs
Option Explicit

```
Private pSKU As String
Private pWidth As String
Private pHeight As String
Private pDepth As String
Private pLeftSwing As String
Private pRightSwing As String
Private pLeftFinishedEnd As String
Private pRightFinishedEnd As String
Private pToeKickHeight As String
Private pAdjShelfQty As String
Private pLeftStileWidth As String
Private pRightStileWidth As String
Private pTopRailWidth As String
Private pBottomRailWidth As String
Private pExtendLeftFFDown As String
Private pExtendLeftFFUp As String
Private pExtendRightFFDown As String
Private pExtendRightFFUp As String
Private pExtendTopRail As String
Private pExtendBottomRail As String
Private pBayHeightCalc As String
Private pBay1Height As String
Private pBay2Height As String
Private pBay3Height As String
Private pBay4Height As String
Private pBay5Height As String
Private pBayWidthCalc As String
Private pBay1Width As String
Private pBay2Width As String
Private pBay3Width As String
Private pBay4Width As String
Private pBay5Width As String
Private pDrawerFrontCalc As String
Private pTopDrawerFront As String
Private pSecondDrawerFront As String
Private pThirdDrawerFront As String
Private pBottomDrawerFront As String

Public Property Get SKU() As String
SKU = pSKU
End Property

Public Property Let SKU(Value As String)
pSKU = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Width() As String
Width = pWidth
End Property

Public Property Let Width(Value As String)
pWidth = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Height() As String
Height = pHeight
End Property

Public Property Let Height(Value As String)
pHeight = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Depth() As String
Depth = pDepth
End Property

Public Property Let Depth(Value As String)
pDepth = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LeftSwing() As String
LeftSwing = pLeftSwing
End Property

Public Property Let LeftSwing(Value As String)
pLeftSwing = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RightSwing() As String
RightSwing = pRightSwing
End Property

Public Property Let RightSwing(Value As String)
pRightSwing = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LeftFinishedEnd() As String
LeftFinishedEnd = pLeftFinishedEnd
End Property

Public Property Let LeftFinishedEnd(Value As String)
pLeftFinishedEnd = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RightFinishedEnd() As String
RightFinishedEnd = pRightFinishedEnd
End Property

Public Property Let RightFinishedEnd(Value As String)
pRightFinishedEnd = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ToeKickHeight() As String
ToeKickHeight = pToeKickHeight
End Property

Public Property Let ToeKickHeight(Value As String)
pToeKickHeight = Value
End Property

Public Property Get AdjShelfQty() As String
AdjShelfQty = pAdjShelfQty
End Property

Public Property Let AdjShelfQty(Value As String)
pAdjShelfQty = Value
End Property

Public Property Get LeftStileWidth() As String
LeftStileWidth = pLeftStileWidth
End Property

Public Property Let LeftStileWidth(Value As String)
pLeftStileWidth = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RightStileWidth() As String
RightStileWidth = pRightStileWidth
End Property

Public Property Let RightStileWidth(Value As String)
pRightStileWidth = Value
End Property

Public Property Get TopRailWidth() As String
TopRailWidth = pTopRailWidth
End Property

Public Property Let TopRailWidth(Value As String)
pTopRailWidth = Value
End Property

Public Property Get BottomRailWidth() As String
BottomRailWidth = pBottomRailWidth
End Property

Public Property Let BottomRailWidth(Value As String)
pBottomRailWidth = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ExtendLeftFFDown() As String
ExtendLeftFFDown = pExtendLeftFFDown
End Property

Public Property Let ExtendLeftFFDown(Value As String)
pExtendLeftFFDown = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ExtendLeftFFUp() As String
ExtendLeftFFUp = pExtendLeftFFUp
End Property

Public Property Let ExtendLeftFFUp(Value As String)
pExtendLeftFFUp = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ExtendRightFFDown() As String
ExtendRightFFDown = pExtendRightFFDown
End Property

Public Property Let ExtendRightFFDown(Value As String)
pExtendRightFFDown = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ExtendRightFFUp() As String
ExtendRightFFUp = pExtendRightFFUp
End Property

Public Property Let ExtendRightFFUp(Value As String)
pExtendRightFFUp = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ExtendTopRail() As String
ExtendTopRail = pExtendTopRail
End Property

Public Property Let ExtendTopRail(Value As String)
pExtendTopRail = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ExtendBottomRail() As String
ExtendBottomRail = pExtendBottomRail
End Property

Public Property Let ExtendBottomRail(Value As String)
pExtendBottomRail = Value
End Property

Public Property Get BayHeightCalc() As String
BayHeightCalc = pBayHeightCalc
End Property

Public Property Let BayHeightCalc(Value As String)
pBayHeightCalc = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay1Height() As String
Bay1Height = pBay1Height
End Property

Public Property Let Bay1Height(Value As String)
pBay1Height = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay2Height() As String
Bay2Height = pBay2Height
End Property

Public Property Let Bay2Height(Value As String)
pBay2Height = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay3Height() As String
Bay3Height = pBay3Height
End Property

Public Property Let Bay3Height(Value As String)
pBay3Height = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay4Height() As String
Bay4Height = pBay4Height
End Property

Public Property Let Bay4Height(Value As String)
pBay4Height = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay5Height() As String
Bay5Height = pBay5Height
End Property

Public Property Let Bay5Height(Value As String)
pBay5Height = Value
End Property

Public Property Get BayWidthCalc() As String
BayWidthCalc = pBayWidthCalc
End Property

Public Property Let BayWidthCalc(Value As String)
pBayWidthCalc = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay1Width() As String
Bay1Width = pBay1Width
End Property

Public Property Let Bay1Width(Value As String)
pBay1Width = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay2Width() As String
Bay2Width = pBay2Width
End Property

Public Property Let Bay2Width(Value As String)
pBay2Width = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay3Width() As String
Bay3Width = pBay3Width
End Property

Public Property Let Bay3Width(Value As String)
pBay3Width = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay4Width() As String
Bay4Width = pBay4Width
End Property

Public Property Let Bay4Width(Value As String)
pBay4Width = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Bay5Width() As String
Bay5Width = pBay5Width
End Property

Public Property Let Bay5Width(Value As String)
pBay5Width = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DrawerFrontCalc() As String
DrawerFrontCalc = pDrawerFrontCalc
End Property

Public Property Let DrawerFrontCalc(Value As String)
pDrawerFrontCalc = Value
End Property

Public Property Get TopDrawerFront() As String
TopDrawerFront = pTopDrawerFront
End Property

Public Property Let TopDrawerFront(Value As String)
pTopDrawerFront = Value
End Property

Public Property Get SecondDrawerFront() As String
SecondDrawerFront = pSecondDrawerFront
End Property

Public Property Let SecondDrawerFront(Value As String)
pSecondDrawerFront = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ThirdDrawerFront() As String
ThirdDrawerFront = pThirdDrawerFront
End Property

Public Property Let ThirdDrawerFront(Value As String)
pThirdDrawerFront = Value
End Property

Public Property Get BottomDrawerFront() As String
BottomDrawerFront = pBottomDrawerFront
End Property

Public Property Let BottomDrawerFront(Value As String)
pBottomDrawerFront = Value
End Property
```

Here's how OrderPrompts is defined inside the form control

```
Public Property Get OrderPrompts() As clsOrderPromptRow
Set OrderPrompts = pOrderPrompts
End Property

Public Property Let OrderPrompts(Value As clsOrderPromptRow)
Set pOrderPrompts = Value
End Property
```

Here's the code I have for the button click

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
Dim Prompt As Control
Dim PageIndex As Long

For PageIndex = 0 To Me.TabControl.Pages.Count - 1
    For Each Prompt In TabControl.Pages(PageIndex).Controls
        'MsgBox (TypeName(Prompt))
        'CallByName(Me.ProductPromptMapping, PromptControl.ControlName, VbGet)
        Select Case TypeName(Prompt)
            Case "TextBox"
                CallByName Me.OrderPrompts, Prompt.Name, VbLet, Prompt.Text
            Case "OptionButton"
                CallByName Me.OrderPrompts, Prompt.Name, VbLet, Prompt.ControlFormat.Value
            Case "CheckBox"
                CallByName Me.OrderPrompts, Prompt.Name, VbLet, CStr(Prompt.Value)
            Case "ComboBox"
                CallByName Me.OrderPrompts, Prompt.Name, VbLet, Prompt.Value
        End Select
    Next
Next
MsgBox (OrderPrompts.Width)
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

The problem i am having is with saving the Checkbox, Combobox, and OptionButton values back to the object. The textbox value works just fine. So I am not sure what to fix. I keep getting either a type mismatch error or null not supported.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `Me.OrderPrompts`? Is it asssigned to an object reference?

Comment: Do you have any code of your Class object  and what's the function CallByName?

Comment: @Thapipo `CallByName` is defined in the `VBA.Interaction` module, it's built-in.

Comment: You'll have to [edit] your post and show us the `Property Let` members being assigned here, and clarify which is throwing a *type mismatch* and which is throwing a *null not supported*. Otherwise it's nothing but guesswork.

Comment: `Property Let`'s are for primitive types.  You need to use `Property Set` for objects.

Comment: The solution to the original problem was that during the iteration of controls i was also picking up the label controls which do not have a .Value property and were throwing and error.  Also controls that were empty were also throwing an error because of how the properties were declared in the class as strings.  I switched all the declarations to variants and works no problem.  However now, i will be adopting the solution below to clean up the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use `Prompt.Object.Value` for all the controls.

[image]

```
Public Sub PrintControls()
    Dim Prompt As Control
    Dim PageIndex As Long

    For PageIndex = 0 To Me.TabControl.Pages.Count - 1
        For Each Prompt In TabControl.Pages(PageIndex).Controls
            Debug.Print "Name:", Prompt.Name, "Value:", Prompt.Object.Value
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

I really liked your concept so I wrote my own class to Save and Load control values.  My class saves references to the controls and their values for easy retrieval.   [Download Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cwmehapl88ujgb/SaveControls.xlsm?dl=0)

When the Save button is clicked a reference to each control on the MultiPage is saved into a Scripting Dictionary.  The Dictionary is then added to an ArrayList and the Dictionary's index in the ArrayList is added to a ListBox.  When the ListBox is clicked the current settings are saved and the previous settings, corresponding to the Listbox's Value, are loaded.

[image]

### Class: SettingsDictionaryClass

```
Option Explicit
Private ControlSetting As Object
Private mTabControl As MSForms.MultiPage

Sub Init(TabControl As MSForms.MultiPage)
    Set mTabControl = TabControl
    Set ControlSetting = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

End Sub

Function Save() As Long
    Dim subDict As Object: Set subDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim PageIndex As Long
    With mTabControl
        For PageIndex = 0 To .Pages.Count - 1
            For Each ctrl In .Pages(PageIndex).Controls
                subDict.Add ctrl, ctrl.Object.Value
            Next
        Next
    End With
    Save = ControlSetting.Count
    ControlSetting.Add subDict

End Function

Sub LoadValues(ListIndex As Long, Optional SaveCurrent As Boolean)
    Dim ctrl
    Dim Settings As Object

    If SaveSetting Then Save

    Set Settings = ControlSetting.Item(ListIndex)
    For Each ctrl In Settings
        ctrl.Value = Settings(ctrl)
    Next

End Sub
```

### Userform: Userform1

```
Option Explicit
Private SettingsDictionary As SettingsDictionaryClass

Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    lboSettings.AddItem SettingsDictionary.Save
End Sub

Private Sub lboSettings_Click()
    SettingsDictionary.LoadValues lboSettings.Value, True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set SettingsDictionary = New SettingsDictionaryClass
    SettingsDictionary.Init TabControl
End Sub
```

Comment: i really dig this.  You took my concept and improved it. I never thought about using the dictionary for the prompts.  This way i can get rid of my class entirely and just use my property.  Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that you liked it.  Thanks for accepting my answer.